# Can't display index.html from React in Spring

Tags: reactjs, spring, api, indexing, deployment

I built the frontend with React and the REST API with Spring. NOw i was trying to connect the two , and created a controller that returns the index.html generated in the vuild folder of the frontend. 
But when i run the app, I'm getting this errors:

No mapping for GET /static/js/2.24af4acc.chunk.js
No mapping for GET /static/js/main.5b0f5e80.chunk.js
...

MY POM:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
        <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v12.16.1</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>6.13.4</npmVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm run build --nomaps</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <copy todir="src/main/resources/static">
                        <fileset dir="src/main/frontend/build" />
                    </copy>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/>
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><title>My App</title>
<link href="/static/css/2.ecffae5e.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="/static/css/main.fcc6280a.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script>!function(e){function r(r){for(var n,f,l=r[0],i=r[1],a=r[2],c=0,s=[];c<l.length;c++)f=l[c],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,f)&&o[f]&&s.push(o[f][0]),o[f]=0;for(n in i)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(i,n)&&(e[n]=i[n]);for(p&&p(r);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,a||[]),t()}function t(){for(var e,r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r],n=!0,l=1;l<t.length;l++){var i=t[l];0!==o[i]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r--,1),e=f(f.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function f(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,f),t.l=!0,t.exports}f.m=e,f.c=n,f.d=function(e,r,t){f.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},f.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},f.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=f(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t=Object.create(null);if(f.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)f.d(t,n,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,n));return t},f.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return f.d(r,"a",r),r},f.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},f.p="/";var l=this.webpackJsonpweb_frontend=this.webpackJsonpweb_frontend||[],i=l.push.bind(l);l.push=r,l=l.slice();for(var a=0;a<l.length;a++)r(l[a]);var p=i;t()}([])</script><script src="/static/js/2.24af4acc.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.5b0f5e80.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

Project structure:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Ogf.png)

Comment: You can't just return the html file. You need to have all the JS files on the client too. Are you sure you're sending all necessary files to the client?

Answer (score 4):

These warnings occur because no interceptor is configured,Use the default settings.
 or you can add the resource file mapping in the MVC configuration file.

```
enter code here
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
<resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
```

Comment: i don't have an MVC file